# Why the zip file which is downloaded from a server using apache.net.ftp cannot be extracted

Tags: java, ftp

I try to download a zip file from a public ftp server (which doesn't require psw or username), and I find that the zip file can be downloaded successfully but cannot be extracted. When I try to extracted, there is an error pop up: "the file cannot be extracted with this program". Here is my code, and I cannot find any problem. Thanks in advance!

```
    String server = "ftp.sec.gov";
    int port = 21;
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

         ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        //    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
         ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
         ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
         String remoteFile1 = "/edgar/full-index/1993/QTR1/form.zip";
         File downloadFile1 = new File("/Users/nancy/Documents/work/INDEX/form.zip");
         OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
         boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
         outputStream1.close();

         if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
            }
         outputStream1.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can the original file be opened?

Comment: @EJP No, cannot be opened....

Comment: So the problem isn't with this code, it is with the original file at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "public" ftp site is an anonymous server **and** does require a username and password. You can use something like

```
ftpClient.login("anonymous", "user@");
```

And you could also simplify your code with a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
try (OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1))) {
    boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
    }
}
```